# Bridgeless graph whose edges are contained in at most one cycle

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I wish to prove that every graph $G$ with the property $$P(G):\text{every edge in $G$ is contained in at most one cycle of $G$}$$ can be $3$-vertex-coloured.

My idea is to prove it for the bridgeless graphs with the desired property. This will actually suffice, because for a general graph with the property $P(G)$, it is either bridgeless and we're done, or it contains a bridge that we remove and we can conclude by a simple induction argument.

Notice that a bridgeless graph $G$ satisfies $P(G)$ if and only if every edge in $G$ is contained in *precisely* one cycle.

For a bridgeless $G$ satisfying $P(G)$, it is intuitive to colour its cycles one by one, and this should always yield an admissible colouring. I am however unable to make this idea precise. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily the fastest way to prove this, but you could first prove that graphs satisfying $P(G)$ have a rather simple structure: if such a graph is connected and bridgeless, then it consists of cycles $C_1,\ldots,C_k$, where each cycle $C_i$ has precisely one vertex in common with $\cup_{j < i} C_j$, the union of the preceding cycles.

You can prove this by starting with any cycle $C_1$. If this is the whole graph, great. If not, there is an outgoing edge from it, which by assumption is contained in exactly one cycle. How can this cycle attach to $C_1$? Then you keep on iterating this.
(Essentially, you are taking an [ear decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition) of the graph. By considering ear decompositions, you can also prove the stronger statement that every minimally $2$-edge-connected graph is $3$-colorable.)

Comment: I think this should work!